# MySQL count duplicate rows as one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help counting rows from the below example

```
ProjectID ScriptID Browser Status
ABC       5001     Chrome  Pass
ABC       5002     FireFox Fail
ABC       5003     Chrome  Pass
ABC       5003     FireFox Pass
ABC       5004     Chrome  Pass
ABC       5004     FireFox Fail
ABC       5005     Chrome  Fail
ABC       5005     FireFox Fail
```

I want the result like:

```
ProjectID Pass Fail
ABC        2    3
```

I have tried the following query, but this does not get the desired result:

```
SELECT projectID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
FROM Results
GROUP BY ScriptID
```

In short, count a script as Pass if it passed in all browser, count it as Fail if it failed in one or all browsers. Include Pass or Fail count for scripts run only on single browser. There can be scripts run in more than two browsers. Please assist.

Comment: Have you written any code to do this yet? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: You can group by `ScriptID`;

Comment: I have the following query that does not get the desired result.

    SELECT  
        projectID,  
        SUM(CASE  
            WHEN Status = '1' THEN 1  
            ELSE 0  
        END) AS Pass,  
        SUM(CASE  
            WHEN Status = '2' THEN 1  
            ELSE 0  
        END) AS Fail  
    FROM  
        Results  
    GROUP BY ScriptID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your attempted query is a good start. You need a subquery in which you group by project id and script id and determine if the nemuber of passes equal with the number of records in that group (pass), or you have at least one fail (fail). Then in the outer query you group by on project id only and sum up the results in the calculated pass and fail fields:

```
SELECT ProjectID, sum(Pass), sum(Fail)
FROM 
    (SELECT ProjectID,
            ScriptID,
            IF(SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*),1,0) AS Pass,
            IF(SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0,1,0) AS Fail
     FROM Results
     GROUP BY ProjectID, ScriptID) t
GROUP BY ProjectID
```